# Is there anyway to monitor the sound card especially from some applications?

Tags: windows, audio, powershell-3.0

I am trying to monitor on my sound card for special frequency and sample rate tones. The interesting tone is from some specific application, like a audio player. After I had searched on google, I could not find any useful ideas or helpful software. I only found some software to monitor my microphone, like Tonedet. It has the similar function as I need, but cound not monitor the audio output (sound card). Is there anyway to monitor my own sound card? As some predefined sound output, then trigger some applications? My system is windows10-64 by the way. Thank you for any useful ideas!

Comment: @LahiruWijesekara Do you mean I need to install a microphone or speaker to listen to my sound output?  I think it is a little superfluous if I know the sound is from the same computer. But this could be a way.

Comment: I think now you have more details added to the question which is good. Now only I understood your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WASAPI to capture the audio that is coming from other applications.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording

As far as listening for a specific tone, you might find the [Goertzel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) helpful.  It's similar to a Fourier Transform, but less computational overhead since you're only focused on a specific frequency.